# Can I prevent X from crashing when I unplug my external monitor?

Tags: xorg, laptop

I have a laptop (Acer TravelMate 8471), which I connect to an external monitor, keyboard etc. when I'm at home.

When I unplug my laptop, I have to remember to go to the Monitor Preferences and turn off the external monitor, and turn on my laptop monitor, otherwise X will crash.

When I plug my external monitor to my laptop, it will automatically switch to that one without any troubles.

I'm running 10.10, and I have an intel graphics card (GMA 4500 I think; i915).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [report an X bug](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Reporting).

Comment: Will do then :) I thought it might have been a solved problem.

Comment: I have a similar problem, did you end up finding a solution?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running into this issue I managed to solve it based on
[Ubuntu 20.04 suspend logs off and wakes up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1391976/ubuntu-20-04-suspend-logs-off-and-wakes-up)
Seems nvidia has some orphaned symlinks to hibernate and resume files that would cause gdm to die and restart when the monitor was unplugged.