# Ubuntu 20.04 suspend logs off and wakes up

Tags: 20.04, suspend

So, after almost 1 year of perfect behavior, Ubuntu started to act strange.
When I "suspend", the screen goes black for a second, then wakes up right away but logged off. Like completely logged off. It takes me to the login screen and I login to my user again to a fresh new session.

Now, here is my system information:

**Laptop**: Alienware M17 R4 with RTX 3080
**System**: Ubuntu 20.04 with Dual boot with the original OEM Windows 10
**UEFI Secure Boot** is enabled and I don't want to disable it as it  messes up with the windows.

I have external keyboard, mouse and monitor, which I tried disconnecting all of them but the issue was still there.

The changes I can think of that happened recently before this behavior are:

1. I installed Wine and PlayOnLinux
2. I probably updated NVIDIA driver and CUDA to 510

I removed Wine and PlayOnLinux and tried reverting the driver to 460 but that didn't solve the problem.

I also tried adding `nouveau.noaccel=1` to the grub entry.

The output of `systemd-inhibit --list --mode=block`

```
WHO   UID  USER  PID  COMM           WHAT                                                     WHY                                                         MODE 
gdm   125  gdm   5668 gsd-power      handle-lid-switch                                        External monitor attached or configuration changed recently block
gdm   125  gdm   5656 gsd-media-keys handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key GNOME handling keypresses                                   block
ahmed 1000 ahmed 6278 gsd-power      handle-lid-switch                                        External monitor attached or configuration changed recently block
ahmed 1000 ahmed 6276 gsd-media-keys handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key GNOME handling keypresses                                   block
```

If, I disconnect the second monitor, it becomes:

```
WHO   UID  USER  PID  COMM           WHAT                                                     WHY                                                         MODE 
gdm   125  gdm   5656 gsd-media-keys handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key GNOME handling keypresses                                   block
ahmed 1000 ahmed 6276 gsd-media-keys handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key GNOME handling keypresses                                   block
```

`dmesg | grep suspend`

```
[    0.075653] You have booted with nomodeset. This means your GPU drivers are DISABLED
[    0.075654] Any video related functionality will be severely degraded, and you may not even be able to suspend the system properly
[    1.348025] nvme 0000:3c:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
```

I noticed the note here about `nomodeset` but I used that when I first installed Ubuntu a year ago on this laptop to get it to work. And for a year I had no issues with it whatsoever.

`cat -n /var/log/syslog | grep -A 10 -B 3 suspend`

```
   296  01:16:38 m17 kernel: [   89.123804] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
   297  01:16:38 m17 NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1644387398.8142] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
   298  01:16:38 m17 NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1644387398.8143] device (88:9F:6F:7B:E7:D7): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
   299  01:16:38 m17 ModemManager[1160]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend
   300  01:16:38 m17 NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1644387398.8147] device (p2p-dev-wlp62s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
   301  01:16:38 m17 NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1644387398.8149] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
   302  01:16:38 m17 NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1644387398.8150] device (wlp62s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
   303  01:16:38 m17 gnome-shell[2575]: Screen lock is locked down, not locking
   304  01:16:38 m17 whoopsie[1633]: [01:16:38] offline
   305  01:16:38 m17 dbus-daemon[1006]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=0 pid=1007 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
   306  01:16:38 m17 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
   307  01:16:38 m17 gnome-shell[3068]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
   308  01:16:38 m17 gnome-shell[3068]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
   309  01:16:38 m17 dbus-daemon[1006]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
--
   460  01:16:56 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2896]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
   461  01:16:56 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2896]: (EE)
   462  01:16:56 m17 ModemManager[1160]: <warn>  [sleep-monitor] inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
   463  01:16:56 m17 gsd-power[3292]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
   464  01:16:56 m17 dbus-daemon[1006]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.login1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.login1.service' requested by ':1.32' (uid=0 pid=1650 comm="/usr/sbin/gdm3 " label="unconfined")
   465  01:16:56 m17 gsd-media-keys[2664]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
   466  01:16:56 m17 upowerd[1410]: Could not acquire inhibitor lock: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
   467  01:16:56 m17 gnome-shell[3068]: JS ERROR: Error getting systemd inhibitor: Gio.DBusError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying#012inhibit/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/loginManager.js:187:55
   468  01:16:56 m17 gsd-power[2679]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
   469  01:16:56 m17 gsd-media-keys[3290]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
   470  01:16:56 m17 gnome-shell[3068]: Ignored exception from dbus method: Gio.DBusError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
   471  01:16:56 m17 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Module drm being skipped.
   472  01:16:56 m17 systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
   473  01:16:56 m17 systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
   474  01:16:56 m17 systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
   475  01:16:56 m17 systemd[1]: Stopped Login Service.
   476  01:16:56 m17 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Module drm being skipped.
   477  01:16:56 m17 systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
   478  01:16:57 m17 dbus-daemon[1006]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.login1'
   479  01:16:57 m17 systemd[1]: Started Login Service.
--
  3045  01:18:41 m17 kernel: [  211.600943] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
  3046  01:18:45 m17 kernel: [  215.802394] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
  3047  01:18:34 m17 rtkit-daemon[1867]: message repeated 7 times: [ Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 2 users.]
  3048  01:18:45 m17 ModemManager[1160]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend
  3049  01:18:45 m17 NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1644387525.4832] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
  3050  01:18:45 m17 NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1644387525.4833] device (88:9F:6F:7B:E7:D7): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
  3051  01:18:45 m17 NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1644387525.4838] device (p2p-dev-wlp62s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
  3052  01:18:45 m17 NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1644387525.4841] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
  3053  01:18:45 m17 NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1644387525.4842] device (wlp62s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
  3054  01:18:45 m17 gnome-shell[5808]: Screen lock is locked down, not locking
  3055  01:18:45 m17 kernel: [  215.804072] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
  3056  01:18:45 m17 whoopsie[1633]: [01:18:45] offline
  3057  01:18:45 m17 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
  3058  01:18:45 m17 dbus-daemon[1006]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=0 pid=1007 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
--
  3145  01:18:50 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[6002]:  for help.
  3146  01:18:50 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[6002]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
  3147  01:18:50 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[6002]: (EE)
  3148  01:18:50 m17 gsd-power[5904]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
  3149  01:18:50 m17 dbus-daemon[1006]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.login1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.login1.service' requested by ':1.142' (uid=0 pid=5591 comm="/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt1 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/use" label="unconfined")
  3150  01:18:50 m17 gsd-power[6318]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
  3151  01:18:50 m17 gsd-media-keys[5890]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
  3153  01:18:50 m17 upowerd[1410]: Could not acquire inhibitor lock: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
  3154  01:18:50 m17 systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
  3155  01:18:50 m17 systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
  3156  01:18:50 m17 systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
  3157  01:18:50 m17 systemd[1]: Stopped Login Service.
  3158  01:18:50 m17 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Module drm being skipped.
  3159  01:18:50 m17 systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
  3160  01:18:50 m17 dbus-daemon[1006]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.login1'
  3161  01:18:50 m17 systemd[1]: Started Login Service.
  3162  01:18:50 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5591]: (EE) systemd-logind: ReleaseControl failed: You are not in control of this session
--
  6117  01:22:38 m17 NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1644387758.2536] device (88:9F:6F:7B:E7:D7): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
  6118  01:22:38 m17 kernel: [  448.535647] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
  6119  01:22:38 m17 kernel: [  448.537689] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
  6120  01:22:38 m17 ModemManager[1160]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend
  6121  01:22:38 m17 NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1644387758.2539] device (p2p-dev-wlp62s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
  6122  01:22:38 m17 NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1644387758.2541] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
  6123  01:22:38 m17 NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1644387758.2543] device (wlp62s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
  6124  01:22:38 m17 gnome-shell[9561]: Screen lock is locked down, not locking
  6125  01:22:38 m17 dbus-daemon[1006]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=0 pid=1007 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
  6126  01:22:38 m17 whoopsie[1633]: [01:22:38] offline
  6127  01:22:38 m17 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
  6128  01:22:38 m17 gnome-shell[9857]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
  6129  01:22:38 m17 gnome-shell[9857]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
  6130  01:22:38 m17 dbus-daemon[1006]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
--
  6214  01:22:44 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[9752]:  for help.
  6215  01:22:44 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[9752]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
  6216  01:22:44 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[9752]: (EE)
  6217  01:22:44 m17 gsd-media-keys[10066]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
  6218  01:22:44 m17 ModemManager[1160]: <warn>  [sleep-monitor] inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
  6220  01:22:44 m17 dbus-daemon[1006]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.login1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.login1.service' requested by ':1.32' (uid=0 pid=1650 comm="/usr/sbin/gdm3 " label="unconfined")
  6221  01:22:44 m17 gsd-power[9653]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
  6222  01:22:44 m17 upowerd[1410]: Could not acquire inhibitor lock: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
  6223  01:22:44 m17 gsd-power[10068]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
  6224  01:22:44 m17 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Module drm being skipped.
  6225  01:22:44 m17 systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
  6226  01:22:44 m17 systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
  6227  01:22:44 m17 systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
  6228  01:22:44 m17 systemd[1]: Stopped Login Service.
  6229  01:22:44 m17 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Module drm being skipped.
  6230  01:22:44 m17 systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
  6231  01:22:44 m17 dbus-daemon[1006]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.login1'
  6232  01:22:44 m17 systemd[1]: Started Login Service.
  6233  01:22:44 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[9347]: (EE) systemd-logind: ReleaseControl failed: You are not in control of this session
--
  8099  01:24:38 m17 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for wine-platform-6-stable, revision 8.
  8100  01:24:38 m17 kernel: [    0.075594] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-28-generic root=UUID=36c586d5-334b-42b4-9d63-51dcbc49196b ro quiet splash nomodeset vt.handoff=7
  8101  01:24:38 m17 kernel: [    0.075690] You have booted with nomodeset. This means your GPU drivers are DISABLED
  8102  01:24:38 m17 kernel: [    0.075691] Any video related functionality will be severely degraded, and you may not even be able to suspend the system properly
  8103  01:24:38 m17 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for postman, revision 148.
  8104  01:24:38 m17 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for pycharm-community, revision 267.
  8105  01:24:38 m17 kernel: [    0.075692] Unless you actually understand what nomodeset does, you should reboot without enabling it
  8106  01:24:38 m17 kernel: [    0.077704] Dentry cache hash table entries: 4194304 (order: 13, 33554432 bytes, linear)
  8107  01:24:38 m17 kernel: [    0.078689] Inode-cache hash table entries: 2097152 (order: 12, 16777216 bytes, linear)
  8108  01:24:38 m17 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for snap-store, revision 547.
  8109  01:24:38 m17 kernel: [    0.078866] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:on, heap free:off
  8110  01:24:38 m17 kernel: [    0.146456] Memory: 32434052K/33310988K available (16393K kernel code, 3512K rwdata, 10492K rodata, 2904K init, 5724K bss, 876676K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
  8111  01:24:38 m17 kernel: [    0.146462] random: get_random_u64 called from __kmem_cache_create+0x2d/0x440 with crng_init=1
  8112  01:24:38 m17 systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems.
--
  8923  01:24:38 m17 kernel: [    1.342068] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: SPD Write Disable is set
  8924  01:24:38 m17 kernel: [    1.342198] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: SMBus using PCI interrupt
  8925  01:24:38 m17 kernel: [    1.342239] hub 1-0:1.0: 16 ports detected
  8926  01:24:38 m17 kernel: [    1.342641] nvme 0000:3c:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
  8927  01:24:38 m17 kernel: [    1.342681] nvme nvme0: pci function 0000:3c:00.0
  8928  01:24:38 m17 kernel: [    1.342905] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:02: WQXM data block query control method not found
  8929  01:24:38 m17 kernel: [    1.344640] acpi PNP0C14:05: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:04)
  8930  01:24:38 m17 kernel: [    1.344865] ACPI: video: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
  8931  01:24:38 m17 kernel: [    1.353643] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:06: WQBC data block query control method not found
  8932  01:24:38 m17 kernel: [    1.353645] acpi PNP0C14:06: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:04)
  8933  01:24:38 m17 kernel: [    1.355157] acpi PNP0C14:07: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:04)
  8934  01:24:38 m17 kernel: [    1.355403] acpi PNP0C14:08: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:04)
  8935  01:24:38 m17 kernel: [    1.357316] intel-lpss 0000:00:15.0: enabling device (0004 -> 0006)
  8936  01:24:38 m17 kernel: [    1.360533] idma64 idma64.0: Found Intel integrated DMA 64-bit
--
 11755  01:25:17 m17 kernel: [   76.937079] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
 11756  01:25:17 m17 NetworkManager[968]: <info>  [1644387917.5672] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
 11757  01:25:17 m17 NetworkManager[968]: <info>  [1644387917.5675] device (88:9F:6F:7B:E7:D7): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 11758  01:25:17 m17 ModemManager[1113]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend
 11759  01:25:17 m17 NetworkManager[968]: <info>  [1644387917.5696] device (p2p-dev-wlp62s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 11760  01:25:17 m17 NetworkManager[968]: <info>  [1644387917.5709] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
 11761  01:25:17 m17 gnome-shell[2648]: Screen lock is locked down, not locking
 11762  01:25:17 m17 NetworkManager[968]: <info>  [1644387917.5714] device (wlp62s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 11763  01:25:17 m17 whoopsie[1565]: [01:25:17] offline
 11764  01:25:17 m17 dbus-daemon[966]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=0 pid=968 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
 11765  01:25:17 m17 gnome-shell[3265]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
 11766  01:25:17 m17 gnome-shell[3265]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
 11767  01:25:17 m17 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
 11768  01:25:17 m17 dbus-daemon[966]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
--
 11852  01:25:21 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2385]:  for help.
 11853  01:25:21 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2385]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
 11854  01:25:21 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2385]: (EE)
 11855  01:25:21 m17 gsd-media-keys[3463]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
 11856  01:25:21 m17 ModemManager[1113]: <warn>  [sleep-monitor] inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
 11857  01:25:21 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2997]: (EE)
 11858  01:25:21 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2997]: Fatal server error:
 11859  01:25:21 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2997]: (EE) systemd-logind disappeared (stopped/restarted?)
 11860  01:25:21 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2997]: (EE)
 11861  01:25:21 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2997]: (EE)
 11862  01:25:21 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2997]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
 11863  01:25:21 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2997]: #011 at http://wiki.x.org
 11864  01:25:21 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2997]:  for help.
 11865  01:25:21 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2997]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
 11866  01:25:21 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2997]: (EE)
 11867  01:25:21 m17 gsd-power[3465]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
 11868  01:25:21 m17 dbus-daemon[966]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.login1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.login1.service' requested by ':1.38' (uid=0 pid=2385 comm="/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt1 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/use" label="unconfined")
 11869  01:25:21 m17 gsd-power[2788]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
 11870  01:25:21 m17 upowerd[1347]: Could not acquire inhibitor lock: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
 11871  01:25:21 m17 gsd-media-keys[2776]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
 11872  01:25:21 m17 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Module drm being skipped.
 11873  01:25:21 m17 systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 11874  01:25:21 m17 systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 11875  01:25:21 m17 systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
 11876  01:25:21 m17 systemd[1]: Stopped Login Service.
 11877  01:25:21 m17 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Module drm being skipped.
 11878  01:25:21 m17 systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
 11879  01:25:21 m17 dbus-daemon[966]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.login1'
 11880  01:25:21 m17 systemd[1]: Started Login Service.
 11881  01:25:21 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2385]: (EE) systemd-logind: ReleaseControl failed: You are not in control of this session
--
 15606  01:28:00 m17 avahi-daemon[959]: Registering new address record for fe80::3063:aff:fee5:d0ad on vethe3d303f.*.
 15607  01:28:02 m17 kernel: [  241.483416] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
 15608  01:28:04 m17 kernel: [  243.443410] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
 15609  01:28:04 m17 ModemManager[1113]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend
 15610  01:28:04 m17 NetworkManager[968]: <info>  [1644388084.1928] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
 15611  01:28:04 m17 NetworkManager[968]: <info>  [1644388084.1929] device (88:9F:6F:7B:E7:D7): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 15612  01:28:04 m17 NetworkManager[968]: <info>  [1644388084.1933] device (p2p-dev-wlp62s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 15613  01:28:04 m17 NetworkManager[968]: <info>  [1644388084.1935] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
 15614  01:28:04 m17 NetworkManager[968]: <info>  [1644388084.1936] device (wlp62s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 15615  01:28:04 m17 gnome-shell[5651]: Screen lock is locked down, not locking
 15616  01:28:04 m17 kernel: [  243.445157] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
 15617  01:28:04 m17 whoopsie[1565]: [01:28:04] offline
 15618  01:28:04 m17 dbus-daemon[966]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=0 pid=968 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
 15619  01:28:04 m17 gnome-shell[8717]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
--
 15700  01:28:07 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5444]:  for help.
 15701  01:28:07 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5444]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
 15702  01:28:07 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5444]: (EE)
 15703  01:28:07 m17 gsd-power[8969]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
 15704  01:28:07 m17 ModemManager[1113]: <warn>  [sleep-monitor] inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
 15705  01:28:07 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[8473]: (EE)
 15706  01:28:07 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[8473]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
 15707  01:28:07 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[8473]: #011 at http://wiki.x.org
 15708  01:28:07 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[8473]:  for help.
 15709  01:28:07 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[8473]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
 15710  01:28:07 m17 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[8473]: (EE)
 15711  01:28:07 m17 gsd-power[5779]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
 15712  01:28:07 m17 upowerd[1347]: Could not acquire inhibitor lock: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
 15713  01:28:07 m17 gsd-media-keys[5766]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
 15714  01:28:07 m17 gsd-media-keys[8967]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
 15715  01:28:07 m17 dbus-daemon[966]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.login1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.login1.service' requested by ':1.171' (uid=0 pid=8473 comm="/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/use" label="unconfined")
 15716  01:28:07 m17 systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 15717  01:28:07 m17 systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 15718  01:28:07 m17 systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
 15719  01:28:07 m17 systemd[1]: Stopped Login Service.
 15720  01:28:07 m17 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Module drm being skipped.
 15721  01:28:07 m17 systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
 15722  01:28:08 m17 dbus-daemon[966]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.login1'
 15723  01:28:08 m17 systemd[1]: Started Login Service.
 15724  01:28:08 m17 dbus-daemon[2388]: [session uid=125 pid=2388] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1' unit='tracker-store.service' requested by ':1.2' (uid=125 pid=2382 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs " label="unconfined")
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

From this log, I noticed a few things:

- `Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7`
- `Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying`
- `Screen lock is locked down, not locking`

Googling these got me nowhere.

If someone can help me here so I don't have to reinstall Ubuntu, I would really appreciate it. Reinstalling the system with everything I need for my work is a painful process for me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The issue is caused by the Nvidia driver upgrades failing to remove newly obsolete links in these directories:

```
/etc/systemd/system/systemd-suspend.service.requires/
/etc/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate.service.requires/
```

The entries to remove should look like this:

```
nvidia-hibernate.service -> /lib/systemd/system/nvidia-hibernate.service
nvidia-resume.service -> /lib/systemd/system/nvidia-resume.service
```

Follow these steps:

1. Make sure the Nvidia related symlinks are really broken
2. Delete the broken Nvidia related symlinks in both directories and the issue should resolve itself

This issue only affected my Ubuntu laptop systems. My Ubuntu desktops did not have these symlinks installed.

The broken symlinks cause X11 sddm to crash when the system resumes from hibernation or suspension.

[There is a bug related to it posted here on the Ubuntu bug site](https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg5950676.html).

Comment: Thankyou! I lost so much work from this bug. For me it manifested as gdm session dying every time I unplugged an external monitor.