# Ubuntu 20.04 logs out instead of suspend/shutdown

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, kernel, suspend, shutdown

I can't suspend Ubuntu, I think since the last update (I think kernel 5.13.0-37 got installed). When I press the shutdown or suspend button, or choose either through a menu, my system logs out instead of performing the respective action, and brings me to the startup screen. No other users are logged in.

What I tried so far, but did not help:

- purged NVIDIA drivers.
- tried using another installed kernel in GRUB: 5.13.0-35.
- installed latest GA kernel for 20.04: 5.4.187.

Suspicious `syslog` entries:

```
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 gnome-shell[46754]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 gnome-shell[46754]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 gnome-shell[46754]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 gnome-shell[46754]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 gnome-shell[46754]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 gnome-shell[46754]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 gnome-shell[46754]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 gnome-shell[46754]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 gnome-shell[46754]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <info>  [1648451751.3923] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 ModemManager[1268]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <info>  [1648451751.3924] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <info>  [1648451751.3928] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <info>  [1648451751.3929] device (enp0s31f6): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <info>  [1648451751.3938] device (wlp2s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3413.999912] audit: type=1107 audit(1648451751.385:765): pid=1124 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="PrepareForSleep" name=":1.659" mask="receive" pid=47333 label="snap.teams-insiders.teams-insiders" peer_pid=46025 peer_label="unconfined"
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3413.999912]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 whoopsie[1967]: [09:15:51] offline
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 dbus-daemon[1124]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=0 pid=1125 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 dbus-daemon[1124]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <info>  [1648451751.4140] device (enp0s31f6): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 avahi-daemon[1119]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::c803:a90d:334c:694a on enp0s31f6.
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 avahi-daemon[1119]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s31f6.IPv6 with address fe80::c803:a90d:334c:694a.
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3414.023946] audit: type=1400 audit(1648451751.409:766): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.teams-insiders.teams-insiders" name="/sys/devices/virtual/net/lo/speed" pid=48802 comm="teams-insiders" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <info>  [1648451751.4160] dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): canceled DHCP transaction
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 avahi-daemon[1119]: Interface enp0s31f6.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <info>  [1648451751.4160] dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): state changed bound -> done
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 avahi-daemon[1119]: Withdrawing address record for 10.0.2.44 on enp0s31f6.
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 avahi-daemon[1119]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s31f6.IPv4 with address 10.0.2.44.
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 avahi-daemon[1119]: Interface enp0s31f6.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <info>  [1648451751.4183] device (enp0s31f6): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3414.025837] audit: type=1400 audit(1648451751.413:767): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.teams-insiders.teams-insiders" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/enp0s31f6/speed" pid=48802 comm="teams-insiders" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3414.032765] audit: type=1400 audit(1648451751.421:768): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.teams-insiders.teams-insiders" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0/speed" pid=48802 comm="teams-insiders" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3414.032784] audit: type=1400 audit(1648451751.421:769): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.teams-insiders.teams-insiders" name="/sys/devices/virtual/net/docker0/speed" pid=48802 comm="teams-insiders" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46251]: dbus-daemon[46251]: [session uid=124 pid=46251] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.13' (uid=124 pid=46441 comm="/usr/libexec/gsd-sharing " label="unconfined")
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46251]: dbus-daemon[46251]: [session uid=124 pid=46251] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 gsd-sharing[46441]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 gsd-sharing[46441]: message repeated 3 times: [ Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1]
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 gnome-shell[46754]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 gnome-shell[46754]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3414.110112] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: NIC Link is Down
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3414.111442] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 76:83:c2:42:8f:c0 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3414.112399] audit: type=1400 audit(1648451751.497:770): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.teams-insiders.teams-insiders" name="/sys/devices/virtual/net/lo/speed" pid=48802 comm="teams-insiders" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3414.112476] audit: type=1400 audit(1648451751.497:771): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.teams-insiders.teams-insiders" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/enp0s31f6/speed" pid=48802 comm="teams-insiders" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3414.112508] audit: type=1400 audit(1648451751.497:772): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.teams-insiders.teams-insiders" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0/speed" pid=48802 comm="teams-insiders" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3414.112538] audit: type=1400 audit(1648451751.497:773): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.teams-insiders.teams-insiders" name="/sys/devices/virtual/net/docker0/speed" pid=48802 comm="teams-insiders" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 wpa_supplicant[1167]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=76:83:c2:42:8f:c0 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 wpa_supplicant[1167]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <warn>  [1648451751.5359] sup-iface[0x55e83c5f7a10,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <info>  [1648451751.5360] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <info>  [1648451751.5361] device (wlp2s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3414.141438] audit: type=1400 audit(1648451751.529:774): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.teams-insiders.teams-insiders" name="/sys/devices/virtual/net/lo/speed" pid=48802 comm="teams-insiders" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 avahi-daemon[1119]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::3f4:db35:bdf:a693 on wlp2s0.
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 avahi-daemon[1119]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::3f4:db35:bdf:a693.
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 avahi-daemon[1119]: Interface wlp2s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <info>  [1648451751.5567] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <info>  [1648451751.5567] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> done
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 avahi-daemon[1119]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.162.5 on wlp2s0.
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 avahi-daemon[1119]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.162.5.
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 avahi-daemon[1119]: Interface wlp2s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <info>  [1648451751.5596] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 wpa_supplicant[1167]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-100
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 wpa_supplicant[1167]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 gnome-shell[46754]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 gnome-shell[46754]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 gnome-shell[46754]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 gnome-shell[46754]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 gnome-shell[46754]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 gnome-shell[46754]: DING: Gjs-Message: 09:11:47.886: JS LOG: Error connecting to Nautilus#012Initializing nautilus-dropbox 2019.02.14#012GNOME nautilus 3.36.3
Mar 28 09:15:51 bart-Precision-3520 wpa_supplicant[1167]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Mar 28 09:15:52 bart-Precision-3520 gnome-shell[46754]: g_dbus_connection_emit_signal: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
Mar 28 09:15:52 bart-Precision-3520 gnome-shell[46754]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Mar 28 09:15:52 bart-Precision-3520 gnome-shell[46754]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <info>  [1648451756.4079] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <info>  [1648451756.4081] device (enp0s31f6): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.014961] kauditd_printk_skb: 15 callbacks suppressed
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.014965] audit: type=1107 audit(1648451756.401:790): pid=1124 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="PrepareForSleep" name=":1.659" mask="receive" pid=47333 label="snap.teams-insiders.teams-insiders" peer_pid=46025 peer_label="unconfined"
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.014965]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 ModemManager[1268]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is resuming
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <info>  [1648451756.5999] device (wlp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.205262] audit: type=1400 audit(1648451756.593:791): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.teams-insiders.teams-insiders" name="/sys/devices/virtual/net/lo/speed" pid=48802 comm="teams-insiders" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.205270] audit: type=1400 audit(1648451756.593:792): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.teams-insiders.teams-insiders" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/enp0s31f6/speed" pid=48802 comm="teams-insiders" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.205311] audit: type=1400 audit(1648451756.593:793): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.teams-insiders.teams-insiders" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0/speed" pid=48802 comm="teams-insiders" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.205386] audit: type=1400 audit(1648451756.593:794): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.teams-insiders.teams-insiders" name="/sys/devices/virtual/net/docker0/speed" pid=48802 comm="teams-insiders" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46636]: (EE) modeset(0): failed to set mode: Permission denied
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.347423] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.0
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.347446] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.347448] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:a111] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.347451] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [12] Timeout               
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.348379] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.0
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.348400] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.348403] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:a111] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.348405] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [12] Timeout               
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.351972] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.0
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.351992] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.351995] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:a111] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.351997] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [12] Timeout               
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.356773] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.0
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.356792] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.356794] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:a111] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.356797] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [12] Timeout               
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.359680] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.0
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.359697] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.359699] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:a111] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.359701] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [12] Timeout               
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.363770] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.0
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.363787] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.363789] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:a111] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.363791] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [12] Timeout               
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.364164] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.0
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.364177] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.364179] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:a111] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.364181] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [12] Timeout               
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.366526] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.0
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.366546] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.366548] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:a111] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.366550] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [12] Timeout               
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.458912] audit: type=1400 audit(1648451756.845:795): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.teams-insiders.teams-insiders" name="/sys/devices/virtual/net/lo/speed" pid=48802 comm="teams-insiders" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.458917] audit: type=1400 audit(1648451756.845:796): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.teams-insiders.teams-insiders" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/enp0s31f6/speed" pid=48802 comm="teams-insiders" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.458919] audit: type=1400 audit(1648451756.845:797): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.teams-insiders.teams-insiders" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0/speed" pid=48802 comm="teams-insiders" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.458922] audit: type=1400 audit(1648451756.845:798): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.teams-insiders.teams-insiders" name="/sys/devices/virtual/net/docker0/speed" pid=48802 comm="teams-insiders" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46636]: message repeated 7 times: [ (EE) modeset(0): failed to set mode: Permission denied]
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <info>  [1648451756.8530] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <info>  [1648451756.8535] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 kernel: [ 3419.476797] audit: type=1400 audit(1648451756.865:799): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.teams-insiders.teams-insiders" name="/sys/devices/virtual/net/lo/speed" pid=48802 comm="teams-insiders" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <info>  [1648451756.9095] sup-iface[0x55e83c5f7b00,wlp2s0]: supports 5 scan SSIDs
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <info>  [1648451756.9111] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <info>  [1648451756.9112] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 NetworkManager[1125]: <info>  [1648451756.9115] device (wlp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 systemd[1]: Stopped Login Service.
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Module drm being skipped.
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46636]: (EE)
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46636]: Fatal server error:
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46636]: (EE) systemd-logind disappeared (stopped/restarted?)
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46636]: (EE)
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46636]: (EE)
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46636]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46636]: #011 at http://wiki.x.org
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46636]:  for help.
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46636]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/bart/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46636]: (EE)
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46636]: (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46121]: (EE)
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46121]: Fatal server error:
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46121]: (EE) systemd-logind disappeared (stopped/restarted?)
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46121]: (EE)
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46121]: (EE)
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46121]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46121]: #011 at http://wiki.x.org
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46121]:  for help.
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46121]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[46121]: (EE)
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 gsd-power[46922]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 gsd-power[46482]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Mar 28 09:15:56 bart-Precision-3520 systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
```

I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: Note the *exact* time you select suspend/shutdown. Then check your logs for that time and the few seconds after.

Comment: @user535733, added syslog suspicious entries in the main question

Comment: Could you see if manually killing Dropbox or MS Teams makes any difference? A common culprit is external devices so you could try disabling BT, WiFi and LAN, and disconnecting anything plugged into your USB ports and see if the PC stops automatically waking from sleep

Comment: @Smurfz87, tried all what you suggested above, for Teams I even uninstalled it completely, but none of that helped

Answer (score 5):

Following the suggestion of my colleague, I checked some NVIDIA links in `systemd` and they were indeed broken:

```
$ ls /etc/systemd/system/systemd-*/*
/etc/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate.service.requires/nvidia-hibernate.service
/etc/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate.service.requires/nvidia-resume.service
/etc/systemd/system/systemd-suspend.service.requires/nvidia-resume.service
/etc/systemd/system/systemd-suspend.service.requires/nvidia-suspend.service
```

The solution to that problem is to delete them, according to [palisadoes](https://askubuntu.com/users/1572310/palisadoes)' [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1393726/618353) in this related thread:
[Ubuntu 20.04 suspend logs off and wakes up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1391976/ubuntu-20-04-suspend-logs-off-and-wakes-up)

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it for me, this problem was driving me up the wall!