# Ubuntu laptop doesn't go in sleep mode

Tags: suspend, 22.04

I have a problem with my laptop: when I put it in standby it keeps running as if it were open.
The problem is that when I take it out of the bag after carrying it, the laptop is hot because it has continued to run without being able to cool down, because it is in my bag. Besides draining the battery unnecessarily, it can't be a good thing for the computer components.
I don't know how to solve this. To put the computer to sleep I tried the menu on the top right of the screen and the command `systemctl suspend -i` which do the same result.

The computer model is Dell Precision 7560, running `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS`. I think I did not have the issue when it was `20.04`.

Is there any way to diagnose what is causing this and then fix it? A few weeks ago I had started to research this, I had seen a page (which I haven't found) that suggested it might be due to the disk encryption system I had put on it.

Comment: Most likely this is the [same issue solved here already](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1391976/ubuntu-20-04-suspend-logs-off-and-wakes-up/1393726#1393726).

Comment: There was indeed the broken links in my `/etc` directory, but remove them did not fix the issue

Comment: EDIT : now it works... Maybe it needed more than just a restart to fix it inside...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Dhiraj Dhule in a comment above :

A similar problem has already been solved on the forum: [Ubuntu 20.04 suspend logs off and wakes up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1391976/ubuntu-20-04-suspend-logs-off-and-wakes-up/1393726#1393726).

It is because symbolic links have been broken.

Comment: If his comment was helpful you certainly should upvote it :)