# Ubuntu 22.04 can't suspend (usb usb: PM: failed to suspend async: error -16)

Tags: kernel, suspend

Have the same issue as [described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1391976/ubuntu-20-04-suspend-logs-off-and-wakes-up/1393726#1393726) but I have integrated graphics.
[specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Fd7Q.png)

So unfortunately this solution doesn't work for me.
This [topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403741/ubuntu-22-04-cant-suspend) described a similar problem, but most people have the problem with NVidia drivers or completely another problem like [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1970957).

From the logs I have the following output:

```
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 ModemManager[850]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 NetworkManager[771]: <info>  [1676203855.1890] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 NetworkManager[771]: <info>  [1676203855.1892] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 google-chrome.desktop[3697]: [3690:3724:0212/131055.189545:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(472)] ConnectionHandler failed with net error: -2
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1750.222055] audit: type=1107 audit(1676203855.184:211): pid=768 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="PrepareForSleep" name=":1.21" mask="receive" pid=6155 label="snap.typora.typora" peer_pid=807 peer_label="unconfined"
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1750.222055]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1750.224113] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1750.226698] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 dbus-daemon[768]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.6' (uid=0 pid=771 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1750.231360] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1750.232725] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 dbus-daemon[768]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1750.233715] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1750.236071] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1750.236991] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1750.238295] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 58:2a:f7:56:d6:f4 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 wpa_supplicant[818]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=58:2a:f7:56:d6:f4 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 wpa_supplicant[818]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 NetworkManager[771]: <info>  [1676203855.3160] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 wpa_supplicant[818]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-9999 noise=9999 txrate=0
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 NetworkManager[771]: <info>  [1676203855.3389] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): canceled DHCP transaction
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 NetworkManager[771]: <info>  [1676203855.3389] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 NetworkManager[771]: <info>  [1676203855.3389] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): state changed no lease
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 avahi-daemon[764]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.2.111 on wlp0s20f3.
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 avahi-daemon[764]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp0s20f3.IPv4 with address 192.168.2.111.
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 avahi-daemon[764]: Interface wlp0s20f3.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 systemd-resolved[593]: wlp0s20f3: Bus client reset search domain list.
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 systemd-resolved[593]: wlp0s20f3: Bus client set default route setting: no
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 systemd-resolved[593]: wlp0s20f3: Bus client reset DNS server list.
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 NetworkManager[771]: <info>  [1676203855.3645] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 NetworkManager[771]: <info>  [1676203855.3652] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 wpa_supplicant[818]: p2p-dev-wlp0s20: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 wpa_supplicant[818]: p2p-dev-wlp0s20: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 wpa_supplicant[818]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp0s20 disabled_11b_rates=0
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 systemd-sleep[8198]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1750.516122] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1750.525840] Filesystems sync: 0.009 seconds
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 wpa_supplicant[818]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 wpa_supplicant[818]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 wpa_supplicant[818]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp0s20f3 disabled_11b_rates=0
Feb 12 13:10:55 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 gnome-shell[2754]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Feb 12 13:10:56 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1750.646369] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
Feb 12 13:10:56 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1750.648683] OOM killer disabled.
Feb 12 13:10:56 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1750.648684] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.020 seconds) done.
Feb 12 13:10:56 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1750.669684] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Feb 12 13:10:56 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1750.694791] PM: dpm_run_callback(): usb_dev_suspend+0x0/0x20 returns -16
Feb 12 13:10:56 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1750.694807] usb usb3: PM: failed to suspend async: error -16
Feb 12 13:10:56 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1750.721616] PM: dpm_run_callback(): usb_dev_suspend+0x0/0x20 returns -16
Feb 12 13:10:56 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1750.721633] usb usb4: PM: failed to suspend async: error -16
Feb 12 13:10:56 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1750.881749] PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
Feb 12 13:10:56 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1751.448174] OOM killer enabled.
Feb 12 13:10:56 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1751.448177] Restarting tasks ... done.
Feb 12 13:10:56 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1751.464634] thermal thermal_zone5: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
Feb 12 13:10:56 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 bluetoothd[767]: Controller resume with wake event 0x0
Feb 12 13:10:56 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1751.510114] PM: suspend exit
Feb 12 13:10:56 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1751.510165] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Feb 12 13:10:56 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1751.521855] Filesystems sync: 0.011 seconds
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1751.528479] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.225 seconds) done.
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1751.754281] OOM killer disabled.
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1751.754283] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.477 seconds) done.
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1752.231622] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1752.237767] PM: dpm_run_callback(): usb_dev_suspend+0x0/0x20 returns -16
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1752.237786] usb usb3: PM: failed to suspend async: error -16
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1752.265637] PM: dpm_run_callback(): usb_dev_suspend+0x0/0x20 returns -16
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1752.265658] usb usb4: PM: failed to suspend async: error -16
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1752.468150] PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1752.541821] OOM killer enabled.
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1752.541825] Restarting tasks ... done.
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1752.566355] thermal thermal_zone5: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 systemd-sleep[8198]: Failed to put system to sleep. System resumed again: Device or resource busy
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 bluetoothd[767]: Controller resume with wake event 0x0
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1752.604356] PM: suspend exit
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 systemd[1]: Failed to start System Suspend.
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Suspend.
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 systemd[1]: suspend.target: Job suspend.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 NetworkManager[771]: <info>  [1676203857.5792] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 ModemManager[850]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is resuming
```

I noticed these lines:

```
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1752.237786] usb usb3: PM: failed to suspend async: error -16
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1752.265637] PM: dpm_run_callback(): usb_dev_suspend+0x0/0x20 returns -16
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1752.265658] usb usb4: PM: failed to suspend async: error -16
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1752.468150] PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1752.541821] OOM killer enabled.
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1752.541825] Restarting tasks ... done.
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1752.566355] thermal thermal_zone5: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 systemd-sleep[8198]: Failed to put system to sleep. System resumed again: Device or resource busy
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 bluetoothd[767]: Controller resume with wake event 0x0
Feb 12 13:10:57 vladyslav-Inspiron-15-5510 kernel: [ 1752.604356] PM: suspend exit
```

I have two USB ports, and one of them doesn't work.
And it looks like it's just physically died.
I tried to plug in iPhone and in `lsusb` stdout nothing about it.

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0c45:6a10 Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 27c6:639c Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix USB2.0 MISC
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And `dmesg | rg -i error` displayed next:

```
[    0.756569] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
[    1.167744] ACPI Error: Thread 1106140416 cannot release Mutex [ECMX] acquired by thread 1089536000 (20210604/exmutex-378)
[    1.167768] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.ECDV._Q66 due to previous error (AE_AML_NOT_OWNER) (20210604/psparse-529)
[    1.275839] ACPI Error: Thread 1091018496 cannot release Mutex [ECMX] acquired by thread 1089536000 (20210604/exmutex-378)
[    1.275867] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.ECDV._Q66 due to previous error (AE_AML_NOT_OWNER) (20210604/psparse-529)
[    2.750230] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro. Quota mode: none.
[    3.048013] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-64.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.383875] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_TZ.ETMD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210604/psargs-330)
[    4.383900] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210604/psparse-529)
[  133.349001] usb usb3: PM: failed to suspend async: error -16
[  133.379682] usb usb4: PM: failed to suspend async: error -16
[  134.877291] usb usb3: PM: failed to suspend async: error -16
[  134.903748] usb usb4: PM: failed to suspend async: error -16
[  163.744127] usb usb3: PM: failed to suspend async: error -16
[  163.770547] usb usb4: PM: failed to suspend async: error -16
[  165.275559] usb usb3: PM: failed to suspend async: error -16
[  165.302551] usb usb4: PM: failed to suspend async: error -16
```

So looks like the problem somewhere here, but how force it to be suspended??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the same bug I report here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2008633, but unfortunately no one has done anything with the bug report yet. Although it's my case it's on hardware with an AMD APU.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).