# Can't suspend/sleep after upgrade to 23.10

Tags: suspend, 23.10, wakeup

After upgrading from 23.04 to 23.10, my laptop can't sleep: when trying to sleep, it immediately wakes up again. This occurs when no peripherals (Bluetooth anything, keyboard, monitor etc.) are connected too.

I have tried toggling "wakeup devices" in `/proc/acpi/wakeup` as in [Ubuntu wakes up after few seconds of sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598236/ubuntu-wakes-up-after-few-seconds-of-sleep), but disabling them all didn't prevent the computer waking up immediately.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the output of `sudo dmesg`?

Comment: Hi @DanielT, thanks for commenting. I've run that, but there's a huge amount of output, too much to quote here. What would you like me to provide?

Comment: You can use https://paste.ubuntu.com/ . If there is nothing obvious in the dmesg and you think this is a kernel bug instead of something config or commands can fix, you can file a bug report by running `apport-bug linux`

Comment: Thanks @DanielT, I can't see anything obvious in the `dmesg`. As this occurred immediately after upgrading to 23.10 and I've tried all config-related solutions I can find, I've created a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2049867).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer here: [Ubuntu 20.04 suspend logs off and wakes up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1391976/ubuntu-20-04-suspend-logs-off-and-wakes-up). Removing these broken nvidia symlinks and then restarting finally fixed this problem for me.